# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel full screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fullscreen, carousel

I'm a complete noob to RoR, Bootstrap and all things code based. I'm trying to implement a full screen Bootstrap Carousel in my RoR app similar to this: http://surfscore.me/

This is what I have so far: http://cryptic-woodland-6000.herokuapp.com/

Can anyone please tell me why I can't get the image to full width....it's driving me crazy!

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <style>

    /* GLOBAL STYLES
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

    body {
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      color: #5a5a5a;
      margin: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
      min-height: 100%;
    }



    /* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
    .logo-holder {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      margin-top: 5%;
      margin-bottom: -90px;
      margin-left: 5%;
      /* Negative margin to pull up carousel. 90px is roughly margins and height of navbar. */
    }


    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }



    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-height: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
      margin: 0;

    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: #0001;
      position: absolute;
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 35px 20px;
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 45%;
      z-index: 20;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }


/* Footer
    -------------------------------------------------- */
.footer {
  padding: -90;
}




    </style>



    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>



  <!-- Logo attempt
    ================================================== -->
<div class="logo-holder">
  <img src="images/hselogo.png">
</div>

  <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>COMING SOON!</h1>
              <p class="lead">We're busy doing some 'market research'!</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
            </div>
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/greek1.jpg" alt="">


        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/hotel.jpg" alt="">

        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/mykonos.jpg" alt="">

        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->




      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer>
        <p class="pull-right">91-93 Buckingham Palace Rd, London, SW1W 0RP.</p>
        <p>&copy; 2013 HOP SKIP ESCAPE LTD &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
      </footer>

    </div><!-- /.container -->




  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The site you're using as an example uses [http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. Can you tell me where I would add this plugin within my app? Thanks

Comment: Well to start you could read the documentation and demos on the site I just linked you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You can achieve a similar effect by dropping the container class

Comment: Thanks for your help Nathan. Please excuse my lack of knowledge but I can't seem to find a container class in the code above. What am I missing. Thanks again.

Comment: It looks like you have some broken html too, Looking at the source you have a <div class="container">  on line 12, then you have a second DOCTYPE dec, followed by another html tag. If you post your layout and view files ill help fix them for you

Comment: Nathan, I really appreciate your help. This is still driving me crazy! I've hashed at the code so much trying to figure it out that I'm not sure what's being used anymore! This is what I have currently: https://github.com/tomwye/HSE/tree/master/app/views/pages

Comment: Nathan, you are my hero! Thank you so much for your time and help. I can finally move on.